# Unity Tweak tool not launching from terminal or launcher

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, unity-tweak-tool

Unity Tweak Tool is not launching from the Dash. My Ubuntu version is 16.04. If I try to run from the terminal I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 33, in <module>
    import UnityTweakTool
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: No module named 'string'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    from email.charset import Charset
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/charset.py", line 15, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
ImportError: No module named 'string'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool", line 33, in <module>
    import UnityTweakTool
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UnityTweakTool/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
ImportError: No module named 'string'
```

Comment: You've already posted a question 4 hours earlier stating that you have errors in your installation. You should focus on fixing that error first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038334/error-in-installing-packages-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Yes @WinEunuuchs2Unix That installation problem is solved now the problem is I can't  open Unity Tweak Tool this python is persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Adding string.py file to python3.5 directory solved my problem. Somehow it was missing from there.

Comment: Please add more information on how to do that.